# How to take the result of two randomly generated values from two functions and add them together?

Tags: javascript, function

Both the first and second functions (n1 and n2) output a random number from their respective arrays into the console. Issues arise when I try to add these two generated values together and have the result displayed in the console as well. I tried creating a global variable to add the results but it did not work.

If n1() outputs 3 and n2() outputs 1, I would like the console to output 4.

Here is my code:

```js
var add = (n1() + n2());

function n1() {
  var cpuSelection =  [1, 2, 3];
  var randomSelection = cpuSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * cpuSelection.length)];
  console.log(randomSelection)
}
    
n1();

function n2() {
  var cpuSelection =  [1, 2, 3];
  var randomSelection = cpuSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * cpuSelection.length)];
  console.log(randomSelection)
}
        
n2();

console.log(add)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log( (n1() + n2()));

function n1() {
  var cpuSelection =  [1, 2, 3];
  var randomSelection = cpuSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * cpuSelection.length)];
  console.log(randomSelection)
return randomSelection;
}
    

function n2() {
  var cpuSelection =  [1, 2, 3];
  var randomSelection = cpuSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * cpuSelection.length)];
  console.log(randomSelection)
return randomSelection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like DM says, you must return those random values.

```
function n1() {
  var cpuSelection =  [1, 2, 3];
  var randomSelection = cpuSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * cpuSelection.length)];
  console.log(randomSelection)
  return randomSelection;
}
    
n1();

function n2() {
  var cpuSelection =  [1, 2, 3];
  var randomSelection = cpuSelection[Math.floor(Math.random() * cpuSelection.length)];
  console.log(randomSelection)
  return randomSelection;
}
```